# Obtaining Captain's name on historical flights?

Tags: pilots

Is it possible to find out the name of the Captain on a previous flight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, no.  As a matter of protecting employees' privacy, that sort of information isn't typically made available beyond what a passenger may notice (nametags) or remember from a PA ("This is Captain Smith...").

In an unusual situation, it might be possible to get a name by contacting the airline, but it's probably unlikely that you'd get an answer back unless the pilot happened to call or write back to you.  Which could happen, but not often.